# scipy minimize on function with multiple inputs, and optimize with multiple bounds

Tags: python, scipy, constraints, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to optimize a function with 2 inputs, each being a list of numbers. I created these similar but simpler version of the function:

```
w1 = [1,2,3] 
w2 = [4,5,6] 
w = [w1,w2]

def objective(x):
    a = x[0][0]**2+x[0][1]**2+x[0][2]**2+x[1][0]**2+x[1][1]**2+x[1][2]**2
    return a 
bnds_1 = tuple((0.1, 1) for w in w1) 
bnds_2 = tuple((0,0.5) for w in w2)

result = minimize(objective,x0=w,bounds=(bnds_1,bnds_2)) 
result
```

where the bound for each number in w1 is (0.1,1) and bound for each number in w2 is (0,0.5)

I get the following error when running the code:

> ValueError: length of x0 != length of bounds

Could you please advise on what's wrong with this?

P.S. I know that I could put both w1 and w2 in 1 list and just call the different items, but was just wondering why this method with 2 inputs doesn't work

Comment: You want one 2 element solution?  Or 3 differerent solution of size 2 (i.e (3,2) solution)?

Comment: Hi hpaulj, sorry I am rather new to scipy so not quite sure what you mean. I am just curious on why I am getting this error and if there is anyway that I could fix it without changing the objective function

Comment: You are getting this error because you are not following `minimize` documentation.  It should state clearly the expected sizes of the initial condition, the bounds, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I need to quote the relevant parts of the `minimize` docs

```
x0 - ndarray, shape (n,)
Initial guess. Array of real elements of size (n,), 
where n is the number of independent variables.
```

`np.array([w1,w2])` is a (2,3) array.  Check the `minimize` code, but I think it will be flattened to (6,).  You could also test the `x` that is passed to `objective`.

```
In [96]: w1 = [1,2,3] 
    ...: w2 = [4,5,6] 
    ...: w = [w1,w2]

In [97]: def objective(x):
    ...:     print('x.shape', x.shape)
    ...:     a = x[0][0]**2+x[0][1]**2+x[0][2]**2+x[1][0]**2+x[1][1]**2+x[1][2]**2
    ...:     return a
```

Run with the 2d initial condition, the `objective` returns:

```
In [99]: objective(np.array(w))
x.shape (2, 3)
Out[99]: 91
```

but called via `minimize`:

```
In [100]: minimize(objective, w)
x.shape (6,)
3     a = x[0][0]**2+x[0][1]**2+x[0][2]**2+x[1][0]**2+x[1][1]**2+x[1][2]**2
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

`x` is (6,) but your function expects a 2 element list of 3 element lists, or a (2,3) array.

And that's not even getting to the `bounds`.

So with `n` being `6`, it is expecting the bounds to be 6 tuples:

```
In [102]: minimize(objective,x0=w,bounds=(bnds_1,bnds_2))
    282     bounds = [(None, None)] * n
    283 if len(bounds) != n:
--> 284     raise ValueError('length of x0 != length of bounds')
```

The key when using `scipy` functions like `minimize` is that YOU have to conform to its usage.  It is in control, not you.

Adapting `objective` to work with this (6,) input:

```
In [110]: def objective(x):
     ...:     #print('x.shape', x.shape)
     ...:     x = x.reshape(2,3)
     ...:     a = x[0][0]**2+x[0][1]**2+x[0][2]**2+x[1][0]**2+x[1][1]**2+x[1][2]**2
     ...:     return a
     ...:
```

And changing the `bounds` to by (6,2):

```
In [111]: minimize(objective,x0=w,bounds=np.array((bnds_1,bnds_2)).reshape(-1,2))
Out[111]: 
      fun: 0.030000000000000006
 hess_inv: <6x6 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
      jac: array([2.00000010e-01, 2.00000010e-01, 2.00000010e-01, 1.00613962e-08,
       1.00613962e-08, 1.00613962e-08])
  message: 'CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL'
     nfev: 14
      nit: 1
     njev: 2
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0. , 0. , 0. ])
```

Answer (score 0):

`minimize` is designed to minimise functions of the form `R^n --> R^1`. The documentation for `minimize` states:

```
fun: callable
  The objective function to be minimized.
  
    fun(x, *args) -> float

  where x is a 1-D array with shape (n,)
```

The `x0` input should be a 1-D array - you are providing a 2-D array for `x0`:  `w = [w1,w2]`. For your system `x0.shape` should be `(6,)`

The bounds parameter should then be:

```
1. Instance of Bounds class.
or
2. Sequence of (min, max) pairs for each element in x. None is used to specify no bound.
```

If you use the second of these then `len(bounds) == 6`, and each of the entries in `bounds` should be a 2-tuple: `(lower_lim_xi, upper_lim_xi)`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. So based on your answer the only way I could use the minimize function here is to have w in the format of [1,2,3,4,5,6], then set bounds as ((0.1,1),(0.1,1),(0.1,1),(0,0.5),(0,0.5),(0,0.5))?

Comment: @user20287252 that's correct. There is another possibility of specifying the bounds as:
```
from scipy.optimize import Bounds
bnds = Bounds(lb=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0], ub=[1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
```